# How to create directory in php?

Tags: php, upload

my current folder path is `$path = car_images;`
Its working for me. i can upload my images into this folder directly.
But i want to create separate folders for each user. so now images should be upload into `$path = car_images/$emp_code;`

means i want to first create directory with name `$emp_code` into `car_images` folder and then into `$emp_code` directory images will upload.

My current code that's not creating directory into car_images folder.

```
           $path = "car_images/".$emp_code;
           if (!is_dir($path.'/'.$emp_code)) 
           {
             mkdir($path.'/'.$emp_code, 0777, true);
           } 
           $name = $_FILES['car_images']['name'][$i];
           $size = $_FILES['car_images']['size'][$i];
           list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $name);
           $file= time().substr(str_replace(" ", "_", $txt), 0);
           $info = pathinfo($file);
           $filename = $file.".".$ext;
           if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['car_images']['tmp_name'][$i], $path.$filename)) 
            { 
               $file_name_all.=$filename.",";
            }
```

Comment: Does the `mkdir` give an warning,  or are there any errors? Also i'd use `$info['extension']` rather than the `$ext`.

Comment: no errors nothing. images are uploded into car_images folder

Comment: Is `$emp_code` set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to work, try it.

```
This is what you want : 

Folder A
   |
   |--Folder_001---All files uploaded/has to be sent here by 001(user 1)
   |--Folder_002---All files uploaded/has to be sent here by 002(user 2)
   |--Folder_003---All files uploaded/has to be sent here by 003(user 3)
   |--Folder_004---All files uploaded/has to be sent here by 004(user 4)
   |--
   |--
   |--so on....
```

> Inside directory:  folder_A(which you already be having), New folders will be generated according to your need.(example: user1_folder, user2_folder..)
>
> For example : when user uploads files, folders can be created according to user_id, Later when user uploads files, 
>   files go into:
>
> folder_A --> User_id_folder --> User_id uploaded files
>   will/can be present/sent here.

**You Can change the below code according to your need, So below I have answered for the asked question.**

Here, $name and $tmp_name required 'Later' for the function move_uploaded_file($parameter1,$parameter2).

```
if(isset($_FILES) & !empty($_FILES)){
       $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      /* $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
       $type = $_FILES['file']['type']; */
       $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; 
    }
```

To set it, I have assumed it as $_SESSION. But you can modify it according to your code like $_POST or $_GET. file_exists() checks whether file/dir is present or not.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['emp_code'])){ 

   $emp_code= $_SESSION['emp_code'];

   if (!file_exists('car_images/'.$emp_code)) {
   mkdir('car_images/'.$emp_code, 0777, true);
}
$location = 'car_images/'.$emp_code.'/';
}
```

Now the directory as $emp_code will be in the folder $car_images, then you move the file to $emp_code directory.

```
     if(isset($name) & !empty($name))
            {
               if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name)){
                   // do the code here.
                  // In the sql query use it as '$location$name'

               /*  FOR EXAMPLE: 
    $sql = "UPDATE `table_name` SET `image`='$location$name' WHERE `email`='$email'";
               */
           }
            else {
               echo "failed to upload";
            }
            }
```

- Now you have car_images folder:
- In that folder, you have all emp_codes generated folders,
- In that folder, you have the files uploaded by them (emp_codes).

Later if this works,  then you can modify code to limited IF statements.
Hope it helped. :)