# uploading an image using PHP

Tags: php

I am making a form in which user can upload data + an image if he likes using jquery ajax and PHP . So far everything works well on the data side, but on the image upload PHP i am having a problem uploading the file to the right location. The query is working fine and submitting the right data to the table. Can you please help me with the image upload. I tried to debug by using a couple of things but so far everything looks right.

here is my php file script:

```
if(isset($_POST['discussion_title'], $_POST['discussion_subjects'], $_POST['discussion_textarea'])) {
    $user_id = (int)$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $title = mysql_prep($_POST['discussion_title']);
    $link = mysql_prep($_POST['discussion_link']);
    $subject = mysql_prep($_POST['discussion_subjects']);
    $discussion = mysql_prep($_POST['discussion_textarea']);
    $discussion_timestamp = time();

    if ($_FILES["discussion_image"]["name"] != "") {
        $test = explode(".", $_FILES["discussion_image"]["name"]);
        $extension = end($test);
        $name = rand(100, 9999999999);
        $file_temp = $_FILES['discussion_image']['tmp_name'];
        $file_path = 'uploaded_pictures/uploads/' . $user_id . '/'. $name .'.'.$extension;
        $file_path = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $file_path);
        move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path); // move_uploaded_file() is a built in function of PHP

        $query = "INSERT INTO discussions_table (user_id, title, link, image_link, subject, discussion, discussion_timestamp) VALUES ($user_id, '$title', '$link', '$file_path', '$subject', '$discussion', $discussion_timestamp)";

        //$save_path = "uploaded_pictures/uploads/" . $user_id ."/$user_id.png";
        $save_path = 'uploaded_pictures/uploads/' . $user_id . '/'. $name.'.'.$extension;
        $save_path_small = "uploaded_pictures/uploads/" . $user_id . "/" . $name.'small.'.$extension;
        create_thumbnail($file_path, $save_path, 250, 250); // creates thumbnail for profile picture
        create_thumbnail($file_path, $save_path_small, 50, 50); // creates thumbnail for small user picture
        var_dump($_FILES['discussion_image']['tmp_name']);
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO discussions_table (user_id, title, link, subject, discussion, discussion_timestamp) VALUES ($user_id, '$title', '$link', '$subject', '$discussion', $discussion_timestamp)";
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
```

and here is the error being given in the alert() because i used var_dump


***Warning**:  move_uploaded_file(uploaded_pictures/uploads/20/499297822.jpg) [function.move-uploaded-file]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **D:\wamp\www\asserter\widgets\discussion_board_submit.php** on line **22**



**Warning**:  move_uploaded_file() [function.move-uploaded-file]: Unable to move 'D:\wamp\tmp\php260.tmp' to 'uploaded_pictures/uploads/20/499297822.jpg' in **D:\wamp\www\asserter\widgets\discussion_board_submit.php** on line **22**



**Warning**:  getimagesize(uploaded_pictures/uploads/20/499297822.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **D:\wamp\www\asserter\includes\create_thumbnail.php** on line **4**



**Warning**:  getimagesize(uploaded_pictures/uploads/20/499297822.jpg) [function.getimagesize]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **D:\wamp\www\asserter\includes\create_thumbnail.php** on line **4**

string(22) "D:\wamp\tmp\php260.tmp"*

Comment: Have you double check if this is the correct upload path "uploaded_pictures/uploads" and is writable by apache

Comment: I don't think you can use a relative path like "uploaded_pictures/uploads..." for the destination. Try using an absolute path like "D:\wamp\www\asserter\widgets\uploaded_pictures/uploads..." instead

Comment: Do you have uploads named directory existing inside uploaded_pictures and the second thing try using giving the full path name D:\wamp\www\asserter\widgets\uploaded_pictures/uploads this will work only if uploads directory exists.

Comment: yes the path is right and i used similar on another page from profile picture upload and it worked fine, but here i had to change some variables for the picture name but it's not working :/

Comment: @Amitoj Singh yes the folder exists

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201067/how-to-create-directory-in-php/50203605#50203605 Your Error seems directory is not properly given , Follow this..It might help you to create directory, but its not the right answer for your above question!

Comment: @HarishKulkarni ok thank you i will recheck my directories

Comment: ok i rechecked my directories and with the other page it is uploading the image on the other page but here not :/

Answer (score 0):

ok it worked. Thanks everyone for your help. The problem was with the directory, i should go back ../ to be able to upload the image

Comment: Also if you're planning database for multi-user, You should be creating directory like I mentioned in that above link to answer. It will help your which user has uploaded what profile images/Files.

Comment: ok done, well i am creating the directories in other function so each user gets his directories. Now i run into other problem which is this : **<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined offset: 1 in <b>D:\wamp\www\asserter\includes\create_thumbnail.php</b> on line <b>40</b><br />**
in this line of code :
``imagecopyresampled($thumb, $src, 0, 0, $src_pos[0], $src_pos[1], $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]);``

Comment: Thats why it was recomended to give complete path

Comment: yes the going back error it can be resolved by giving complete path

Comment: i found the bug ! it was a naming issue

Answer (score 0):

[How to create directory in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201067/how-to-create-directory-in-php/50203605#50203605) - Use this to create directories, I have answered over there. It will help you to create directories for multi-user. Later you can get which user has uploaded what all files.

for error Undefined offset : 1 in php you should set the values using isset() for
$src_pos[1] , $new_size[0], $new_size[1], $size[0], $size[1]

Comment: this is a function that creates a thumbnail i can't post it here because doesn't fit, it again works perfectly on other page which uploads a profile image, but here it is giving this error on this page of the form post

Comment: Ok I understand. Can you Set it using Isset() either outside or inside that function ?

Comment: Array index has to be set

Comment: what do you mean ? does offset 1 mean the second argument ?

Comment: No it doesn&#39;t mean 2nd argument... The array you are using has to be set. If you are using Post or Get or something. You have to set it Using Isset() later in that loop you add those functions. 
Or
you should set  all Array indexes for $src_pos[0] and all separately.

Comment: You can also google Undefined index : 1 in Php. It gives idea how to set.

Comment: ok i will move this to a new thread where i will be able to post everything related, the thing is the thumbnail is being created but still getting this error and the original file image does not get moved in the folder

Comment: here is the new thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429249/error-in-create-thumbnail-function

Comment: yes i did googled it but it is talking about something else

Comment: ok i see what you mean, but where should i use isset() ? is it in the create_thumbnail() function or where i am processing $_FILES ?